# Is there a plugin for eclipse that packages .deb files for an existing project?

Tags: eclipse, deb

I was wondering if there is a plugin for Eclipse that allows the user to build a version of the project/application that is packaged in a .deb?

If possible to be able to modify the configurations before building it.

Comment: I'd actually love to see a plugin set for Eclipse that helped with authoring Debian packages - I always find it such a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plugin that does this.  This is because Eclipse has never been made for that purpose, and therefore does not include all the particulars of Ubuntu Packaging.  Any plugin that might do this would be sketchy at best, and would probably screw up the package in a manner that violates Debian packaging.

(Ubuntu is based off of Debian, and uses Debian .deb package formats :P)

Comment: hmm... why would it be sketchy though? And why would it definitely violate the Debian Packaging Policies? Also, I think there is a RPM plugin in Eclipse if I'm not mistaken (under Linux Tools or something similar)

PS: I know that Ubuntu is based off Debian, and the .deb formats :)

Comment: RPM is easier than Debian.  In Debian, you'd need to make sure versions are changed, the changelog is changed, you'd have to build the source package and make sure lintian doesnt explode on you, among other things.  I've seen people make "packaging plugins" for Debian packaging within an IDE, but I have yet to see one of those succeed.  And i didnt say it would definitely violate it.  Did I use the words "would definitely screw up the package in a manner that violates Debian packaging"?  No i did not.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will accept this as an answer if no one suggests something else. And sorry for the misreading that ;)

Comment: No problem, @Tamer.  :)